# How to search a text document by position

Tags: matlab

I need to search a text file that is about 30 lines.  I need it to search row by row and grab numbers based on their position in the text file that will remain constant throughout the text file.  Currently I need to get the first 2 numbers and then the last 4 numbers of each row.  My code now:

```
FileToOpen = fopen(textfile.txt) 

if FileToOpen == -1 
     disp('Error') 
     return; 
end

while true 
     msg = fgetl(FileToOpen) 

     if msg == -1 
         break; 
     end

end
```

I would like to use the `fgetl` command if possible as I somewhat know that command, but if their is an easier way that will be more than welcome.

Comment: sorry about the ` for the formatting just ignore them i was having difficulty  getting the code to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good start. You should be able to use `msg - '0'` to get the value of the numbers. For ascii code the digits are placed next to each other in the right order (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). What you do when you subtract with `'0'` is that you subtract msg with the ascii code of `'0'`. You will then get the digits as

```
tmp = msg - '0';
idx = find(tmp>=0 & tmp < 10); % Get the position in the row
val = tmp(idx); % Or tmp(tmp>=0 & tmp < 10) with logical indexing.
```

I agree that `fgetl` is probably the best to use for text without specific structure. However, in case you have a special structure of the text you can use that and thus be able to use more effective algorithms.

In case you was actually after finding the absolute position of the digits in the text, you can save the `msgLength = msgLength + length(msg)` for every iteration and use that to calculate the absolute position of the digits.